# Parsing a "String"( char array) in C for string ,int and int

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing

I have a UDP socket server and client set up where the client asks for some information from the server, sending a request in the form of a char array that holds the [ID, " ",choice, " ", request] which are a string, int, and int respectively. I need to be able to parse these three parameters out of the array to access my database to send the correct information back. So far I have tried using a while loop to parse through these, but unfortunately This is not working.any suggestions to a better solution that works? The first int will be one digit long, the second however can be however long.

```
char *idToCheck;
int k = 0;
while(strcmp(messBuffer[k]," ") == 1){
    idToCheck += messBuffer[k];
}
int choice = messBuffer[k++];
int request;
while(strcmp(messBuffer[k],"\0") == 1){
     ????
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear how your data is encoded. Are the integers also strings in the packet, or are they binary values?  If so, which size? You should show an example hex dump of the UDP payload you're trying to parse.

Comment: read the whole message (be sure to get all the message) into a local buffer, then use something like sscanf() to parse out the three items into individual variables.

Comment: user36... you actually have the perfect answer I was looking for. Super simple and super awesome!! i wish i cld make yours the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- You need to have idToCheck point to or be defined to have some storage.
- Don't use strcmp to compare characters - just use ==

How about this to start you out - assumes the Id won't be longer than MAX_ID_LEN.

```
#define MAX_ID_LEN  80
char idToCheck[MAX_ID_LEN]
int i;

for (i = 0; i < MAX_ID_LEN; i++) {
   if (messBuffer[i] != ' ') {
       idToCheck[i] = messBUffer[i];
   }
   else {
       break;
   }
}
```